# How to update events FULLCALENDAR

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

first of all i dont have a fluent english so i am sorry for this :s

So my  first problem is that i have a infinite loop  on the else of the function"get_events" and i dont really understand why

the second one is when i click on a checkbox i have to update events(if the checkboxes is true and i click on it some events have to be deleted and if it's false some event have to appears)
but i can just clear all events

```js
 <script>


    var cards = <?=$cards_json?>;
    var events = []; 
    var calendarEl;
    var calendar;
    
    

   $(function() {
    getCalendar();
     var count = $(".check:checked").length;
        console.log(cards);
        $(".check").prop('checked', true);

        get_events();
      
         $('.check').click(function(){
          var checklist = [];
        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".check:checked");
        //  console.log(checkboxes);
        checklist.length = 0;
        

       
          
       
        for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
            if(checkbox.checked){
              checklist.push(checkbox.value);
              console.log("pourquoi :" + checkbox.value);
            }               
        } 

       
        getNewCards(checklist); 
             
        });       
   
         

   });
   
   
   function get_events(){
     events.length = 0;
     var tmp = [];
     tmp.length = 0;
     calendar.removeAllEvents();
     console.log(cards + " boucle infinie");
    for (let card of cards){
            if(card){
              if(card.dueDate > '<?=date("Y-m-d")?>'){
                console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
                tmp.push( {
                title : card.title,
                start : card.dueDate,
                color: "green",
                });
              }else{
                console.log("infinite loop");
                tmp.push( {
                title : card.title,
                start : card.dueDate,
                color: '#' + card.BoardID + card.BoardID + card.BoardID,
                textColor: 'red',
                });
              }   
            }
    }
    events = tmp;
    for(let event of events){
      calendar.addEvent(event);
    }
    
   
   }
   function getCalendar() {  
        calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listMonth'
        },
        initialDate: '<?=date("Y-m-d")?>',
        navLinks: true, 
        businessHours: true, 
        selectable: true,
        events: events,
        });

        calendar.render();
    } 

    function getNewCards(checklist){
      $.post('calendar/test',{boards:checklist},function(data){
       cards = data;
       console.log("testtttt" + cards);

      }).done(function() {
      get_events();
      
});
      
      

    }
    


</script>
```

```html
<body>
    <?php include('menuNavigation.html'); ?>
    <p>Connecté en tant que :  <?=$fullName?> </p>
    <p>
    <div id='list_board'>
      <?php foreach ($boards as $board):?>
        
          <input type="checkbox" id="check<?= $board->get_id() ?>" name="check" class="check" value="<?= $board->get_id() ?> ">
          <label for="check"><a class="board" href='board/affiche/<?= $board->get_id() ?>'><?= $board->get_title() ?></a></label>
        
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    </p>



    <div id='calendar'></div>

    
  </body>
```

Thx for ur help guys and i am really sorry for my english !

Answer (score 0):

This line: `calendar.removeAllEvents();` -- I don't think that is a real function, are you getting an error on it? I think you want `calendar.removeEvents();`

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/removeEvents

The infinite loop problem probably stems from the `get_events()` function being called 3 times. The first in the `calendar` initialization, then immediately after you check your checkboxes, then immediately again in the `$(function() {` init function, then immediately after in `getNewCards`

You should

- initialize your calendar
- check all the checkboxes
- call `getNewCards()` which will call `get_events()`

remove all other calls to `get_events()`

Comment: Hello, thx for your answer. No i dont have any errors with removeAllEvents. I am not sure to understand The first time i call getEvents it's first the page loads and the second one is every time i click on a checkBox no ? Gonna try this tomorow. thx again

Comment: It didn't solve the issue but i think i understand the problem. I dont understand why but it seems that "cards" is not encoded as json  when i am supposed to update the events.